# Sprintf in perl, Equivalent in Python

Tags: python

I've a code in perl,

```
$abc = sprintf("%.5f", 15.4595255213733);
print ($abc) // 15.45953
```

I'm looking for an equivalent to sprintf in python? or how would I be able to achieve this

Comment: a='%.5f'%(15.4595255213733)

Answer (score 2):

This is called [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
print('{:.5f}'.format(abc))
```

The "old" way to do this would be:

```
print('%.5f' %abc)
```